# Find schema discrepancies between two databases

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have a development database that possibly underwent changes to the schema since the installer was last updated, and a test database that is exactly like the installer would create a new database on a new server.

I can't just make a script for "create database" from the development DB, because this would break on incremental updates.

So, what is the easiest (most automated, that is) way to compare the schemas and see all differences?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987856/how-can-i-find-the-differences-between-two-databases

Comment: IS this a one-time problem?  If so, there's several diff tools for database comparison available.  You can download a demo for most of them for up to two weeks.

Comment: We use Visual Studio to do such work; SQL Server database projects can be used to run schema comparisons and write changes as required. Other tools are available. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx